# postNotification access a different instance of the observer

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsnotificationcenter

I have a class A(Listener) that in his init method observes for a Notification and instantiate and inflate an NSMutableArray

When class B(Sender) posts a notification to the observer of Class A,
it properly calls the method declared in the selector BUT inside the method my instance variable NSMutableArray points to 0x000000

might the notification run in a different istance of the class? may I solve buy declaring A as a Singleton

```
@implementation ClassA
@synthesize myArray;

-(id) init {
    if (self = [super init]){
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(methodThatGetsCalled:)
                                                     name:@"dispatchMethods"
                                                   object:nil];

        classB = [[ClassB alloc] init];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)anotherClassAMethod {
   // first i populate my array
   myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:eventsArray];
   // than i call Class B
}
- (void)methodThatGetsCalled:(NSNotification)note {
    // when the notification is posted, this method gets called but...
    myArray; //points to 0x000000 here
}
```

Comment: Can you post your init method?

Comment: Perhaps you are passing the variable wrong. Lets see some code!

Comment: done, the cleanest possible

Comment: Probably, the best way to go is to add a break point to the `myArray` initialization.

Comment: when do you call `anotherClassAMethod` ? In the init?

Comment: yeah and it works properly, it is filled up with objects, i work with it before calling ClassB and waiting back for the postNotification,
exactely when the debugger came back to ClassA myArray has no value

Comment: sorry @Warren the answer was for Mazygod
for you is "in the class that instantiate ClassA, not provided in the example"

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying here is ...

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(methodThatGetsCalled:)
                                                     name:@"dispatchMethods"
                                                   object:nil];
```

Anytime anyone (it doesnt matter who) shouts out `"dispatchMethods"` all instances of `ClassA` fire `methodThatGetsCalled:`

So you want to be a bit more selective and only listen when a particular instance posts.

```
classB = [[ClassB alloc] init];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(methodThatGetsCalled:)
                                                     name:@"dispatchMethods"
                                                   object:classB];
```

In this case you will only hear the notification if `classB` is the posting object as in when you post from `classB`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"dispatchMethods" object:self userInfo:nilOrWhatever]
```

So if you have multiple instances of `ClassA` and `ClassB` youre quite right in that another instance is hitting `methodThatGetsCalled:` before the array has been instantiated in `anotherClassAMethod`

Comment: i have no problem in letting the observer "opened" to other classes,
my problem is that when the method after the postNotification gets called, and it does, it has no access to the date inside the NSarray, that i'm sure was there.

Actually declaring the variable Global to al instances it seem to work, but it doesn't look like the proper way of doing it,
so back to my first point does the notification calls the class in a somewhat statical way or makes another instance?